# I try to find the row with the minimum sum in a 2D array but I only get 0

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, minimum

Why do I get 0's for minRow and minRowIndex? Thank you whoever response.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test1 {

public static void main(String[] arg) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int [][] matrix = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {3, 4, 5, 6, 7}};

    int minRow = 0;
    int minRowAvg = 0;
    int minRowIndex = 0;

    for (int row = 1; row < matrix.length; row++){
        int rowSum = 0;
        for (int col = 0; col < matrix[row].length; col++){
            rowSum += matrix[row][col];
        }

        if (rowSum < minRow && rowSum > 0){ 
            minRow = rowSum;
            minRowIndex = row;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Row " + minRowIndex + " has the minimum sum of " + minRow);

    }

}
```

Comment: Your code needs more formatting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rowSum` will never be smaller the `minRow`, since you initialized `minRow` to 0.

You should initialize it to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

```
int minRow = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think of that

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in your first loop, the row variable starts at 1 so you never check your first matrix row, it should start at 0.

Your minRow is initialized at 0 and is only modified in your

```
if (rowSum < minRow && rowSum > 0){ 
        minRow = rowSum;
        minRowIndex = row;
}
```

Your condition is always false because rowSum is always superior to minRow. This is the same issue with your minRowIndex.